# Keeping order of blocks like in backend

Tags: templating, craft3, forloop

Fairly new user here.
I am kinda confused how to template. I want to rearrange the order of blocks in my backend and show them in the right order in the front.

Here is how i am currently writing a template.

- Created a section called "Homepage"
- Then I made a matrix block "content blocks"
- After that I created 3 Blocks and called them "Image left", "Image right", "Full Text"
- Went into my `_entry.html` and wrote some for loops. Example

```TWIG
{% for block in entry.contentblocks.type('imageLeft') % }
    do something
{% endfor %}
```

Now when I order those fields in my backend it won't show the right order on my frontend.

Example:

Backend order:

- imageLeft
- imageRight
- imageLeft

Frontent view:

- imageLeft
- imageLeft
- imageRight

I know this is happening because the first for loop will check all first and print them one after another before moving to the next for loop.

How do I prevent this?

I seriously hope somebody understands my issue.  I am fairly new to Twig and Craft so I take every pointer I can get.

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling real adventurous you can do something like this:

```
{% for block in entry.contentblocks %}
   {% include "_about-partials/" ~ block.type %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this instance I'd keep files in a directory named _about-partials with the same name as the block type (_about-partials/imageLeft.html)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a switch condition in my for loop and everything went well. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware the answer has been given already , but I just wanted to point out that the [Craft documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/) has a nice code sample on how to handle this as well.

As the other answers already state, it basically boils down to looping over the blocks and using a switch case (or if/else statements) to determine the type and act accordingly.

The relevant part of the documentation can be found [at this link](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/matrix-fields.html#templating).